# Avoiding edges in 2-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

The task is to build a program that takes an array like so :
                                                            # 0 -1 0#
                                                            # 0 0 -1#
                                                            # 0 0 -1#
And replace all the zeroes with the amount of bordering cells that contain "-1". Like so :
          #1 -1 2#
          #1 3 -1#
          #0 2 -1#

I have currently solved this by adding a "buffer zone" to the array to avoid out of bounds exceptions.

```
public class ArrayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[][] fields = {  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                            { 0, 0, -1, 0, 0 },
                            { 0, 0, 0, -1, 0 },
                            { 0, 0, 0, -1, 0 },
                            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }};

        int pos_x = 1, pos_y = 1, t_x = 1, t_y = 1, sum = 0, maxy = fields[0].length-1, maxx = fields.length-1;

        System.out.println(fields[1][1] + " " + fields[1][2] + " " + fields[1][3]);
        System.out.println(fields[2][1] + " " + fields[2][2] + " " + fields[2][3]);
        System.out.println(fields[3][1] + " " + fields[3][2] + " " + fields[3][3]);

        // xloop
        for (pos_x = 1; pos_x < maxx; pos_x++) {
            // yloop
            for (pos_y = 1; pos_y < maxy; pos_y++) {

                if (fields[pos_x][pos_y] != -1) {

                    // t_x loop
                    for (t_x = pos_x - 1; t_x <= pos_x + 1; t_x++) {

                        // t_y loop
                        for (t_y = pos_y - 1; t_y <= pos_y + 1; t_y++) {
                            if ((fields[t_x][t_y] == -1)) {
                                sum += 1;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    fields[pos_x][pos_y]=sum;
                    sum=0;
                }

            }
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(fields[1][1] + " " + fields[1][2] + " " + fields[1][3]);
        System.out.println(fields[2][1] + " " + fields[2][2] + " " + fields[2][3]);
        System.out.println(fields[3][1] + " " + fields[3][2] + " " + fields[3][3]);

    }

}
```

However, this seems crude to me and I´d prefer a solution that does not alter the original array. I´ve tried a few things but so far I failed to solve it. Any pointers would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If you have a fixed dimension array, as you've used in the code here as `fields`, you know ahead of time what the valid indexes are and don't need a buffer. If the array is coming in as an argument (in the args[] array, for instance), the array and each sub array has a `Length()` property that will tell you what the valid upper index is, and the lower index is always zero. Any Java tutorial on arrays will explain how they work. In either case, you don't need a *buffer* or protective zone.

Comment: That was my first approach, I used maxx=fields.length and tried it without the added zeroes around the original array(which was 3x3). However I could not figure out how to write the arguments for the for loops (ex for (t_y = pos_y - 1; t_y <= pos_y + 1; t_y++) ) so that it wouldn´t go outside of the array.

Comment: To start with, you decompose your code into logical methods that do only one thing - such as counting all the bordering cells with a certain value. Then you can enhance the logic in those method (for example, by not including cells that are out of range of the array) without impacting the overall readability of your code. Another option would be encapsulation: make a new class representing the grid Array, with an accessor method for cell values that returns a particular default value for any cell that is out of range of the array.

Comment: You want to make the code logic like `Mines` game.

Comment: Do you manage to solve your problem or still searching ... ?

Comment: I was able to use the "crude" solution for my homework but I will come back to it in time. I'm pretty sure I know how to do it after splitting the code into multiple methods. But thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, Consider to have a look at this  https://gist.github.com/ianfleeton/10498523 , he make it with simple code and straight  forward method.